# Search for a string inside a tuple, inside a list, inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

If I have a dictionary like this:

```
people = {'comedians': [('123456', 'Stephen Merchant'),
                        ('666999', 'Ricky Gervais'),
                        ('987654', 'Karl Pilkington')],
          'actors': [('366845', 'Bob DeNiro'),
                     ('475684', 'Christopher Walken')]
          }
```

How can I search if the string '123456' exists in `people['comedians']`?

I know I can access the element directly with `people['comedians'][0][0]`, but I can't see how I can search if it exists when given multiple tuples in a list.

I don't need to return the name associated with the number, just that it exists.

Comment: iterate over the list and check the tuple key value

Comment: Hello mr. itzafugazi, try this code,                                                         
people = {'comedians': [('123456', 'Stephen Merchant'),
                        ('666999', 'Ricky Gervais'),
                        ('987654', 'Karl Pilkington')],
          'actors': [('366845', 'Bob DeNiro'),
                     ('475684', 'Christopher Walken')]
          }


#Search value variable.
search_val = '123456'

for i in people:
 for j in range(len(people[i])):
  if (people[i][j][0]==search_val):
   print(people[i][j][0]," value is found.")
  else:
   print("Not Found!")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any) with a generator:

```
if any(tup[0] == '123456' for tup in people['comedians']):
    print('found 123456')
```